# get all the harmonics from a wave

Tags: r, audio

I need to filter the harmonics of an audio track using the libraries 'seewave' and 'tuneR' of R, but I do not know the functions of this language well.
So far I have done the following:

```
library('seewave')
library('tuneR')
track<-readMP3('empty_spaces.mp3')
t1<-cutw(track, from=0, to=10)
autoc(t1, f=4400)
```

and the result is the next screen:
[image]

at first I thought that the group of points on the bottom were the harmonics and the points isolated above belonged to noise, but I think I'm not interpreting it well. Could someone help me interpret this image? or tell me what function would help me get what I need?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is image of distribution of frequencies across time, so by this image it s hard to see, where noise and where useful signal. To solve your problem, you should use frequency filters , chebyhev or butterworth filters (look at `filter` function in `signal` package)  and of course you must know what frequencies you want to delete.